# Url Rewriting from Custom post

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Problem in hand :

I have custom categories in wordpress named "Product Categories" with custom post type "Products".

I want to change urls from

`somesite.com/product/airconditioner/voltas/productname`

to

`somesite.com/airconditioner/voltas/productname`

Code to register post and categories

```
class aw_products_post_type {

function __construct(){
   $this->aw_register_post_type();
   $this->aw_add_post_type_actions();
   $this->aw_add_post_type_filters();
}

public function aw_register_post_type(){        
    // Labels
$labels = array(
    'name' => __('Products','framework'),
    'singular_name' => __('Product','framework'),
    'add_new' => __('Add new','framework'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add new product','framework'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit','framework'),
    'new_item' => __('New product','framework'),
    'view_item' => __('View product','framework'),
    'search_items' => __('Search product','framework'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No product found','framework'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No product found in trash','framework'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Products','framework')
);

$short_url = (get_option('tz_products_short_url') != '') ? get_option('tz_products_short_url') : 0;
$slug_first_part = ((get_option('tz_custom_products_slug') != '') ? get_option('tz_custom_products_slug') : 'product');
if($short_url == 1) {
    $slug = $slug_first_part;
} else {
    $slug = $slug_first_part."/%product_category%/%product_brand%";
}

// Arguments
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/admin/admin-products.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => $slug), // Permalinks format
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
    'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt', 'comments', 'tags')
);
```

Solutions tried in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
</IfModule>
```

This solution is not working; it is causing a error "Too many redirects"

I also tried removing 'product' from

```
$slug_first_part = ((get_option('tz_custom_products_slug') != '') ? get_option('tz_custom_products_slug') : 'product');
```

this line referred from above given code to register custom post type.

Comment: Did you activate the theme and reactivated it again? Wordpress updates the permalinks on theme activation.

Comment: Rewrite mod solution causing too many redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
$slug = $slug_first_part."/%product_category%/%product_brand%";
```

Removed this $slug_first_part. from above code.